# Set directive data after ajax request

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my page controller I get data from an ajax call using ngResource:

```
clientResource.query(
    {
        searchText: vm.search.text,
        pageSize: vm.pageSize
    },
    (data, headers) => {
        vm.clients = data;
        vm.headers = JSON.parse(headers("X-Pagination"))
        // ...
```

I have a directive for the pagination which is simply:

```
<ix-pager headers="vm.headers"></ix-pager>
```

In the directive controller, I have:

```
function ixPagerController($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.headers = $scope.headers;
}
```

Now when the directive renders and the directive controller fires, `$scope.headers` is `undefined`, which is because the AJAX call hasn't returned yet. But when it does and `vm.headers` is set, this doesn't update the model on the directive. So I can change my directive to use a link function with a watch statement, like so:

```
return {
    templateUrl: "/app/partials/pager.html",
    restrict: "E",
    controller: ixPagerController,
    controllerAs: "vm",
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch("headers", function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue) {
                //scope.headers = newValue;           
            }
        });
    },
    scope: {
        headers:"="
    }
}
```

The problem is, at the commented out line, if I set a breakpoint, the `scope.headers` value is ALREADY the correct value, i.e. it has already been set. However, on the directive, template:

```
<pre>{{vm.headers|json}}</pre>
```

Still shows nothing. It's almost as if there's a missing digest or something. How do I get the model on the directive to update the view correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This is what seems to work:

```
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var c = ctrl;
            scope.$watch("headers", function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    c.headers = newValue;
                }
            });
        },
```

Comment: i get the same problem and i solve it like you do. you can also stop the watch process if you want `var stopWatch = scope.$watch("headers", function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    c.headers = newValue; stopWatch();
                }
            });`